# Issue handling array JQuery to PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am getting no response with the following, i am trying to split the array into blocks of 7 values. Although this is not responding whatsoever. I have verified this against the reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php however cannot get it working. Any advice?

```
$array = $_POST['myarray'];
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 7);

    foreach ( $chunked as $row ) {
        foreach ( $row as $value ) {
           echo $value;
        }
        echo "\r\n" ;       

}else{

}
```

Comment: You must show how you are sending the array to the server and how you are trying to insert it into MySQL.

Comment: @BradleyTrager Edited the question to show the ajax sending the array to the php. The array reaches the php, and i can echo the array showing all values in the entire array. The issue is i need to somehow split the values to the 7 value blocks. And then each block needs to insert to a row of the mysql.

Comment: Aren't you splitting the array up in your foreach loop? You can do the inserts to the database there if you need to.

Comment: Thats what i thought, however all the values are in one chunk. I need the first 7 values to be respective to one row in the mysql, then the next 7 to the next row etc. Currently, the foreach will place values in the table respective of only one row. @JayBlanchard

Comment: What do you get if you will do `print_r($array)`?

Comment: i am getting an array now, but i cannot seem to segregate the chunks by foreach loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is insert every 7 items from the array into the table then use array_chunk to divide up the array -

```
$array = $_POST['myarray'];
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 7);
```

Then you loop through `$chunked` and do your database inserts in that loop.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

EDIT: Here is a demo of how to loop through each chunk and get the values -

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($chunked); $i++) {
    foreach($chunked[$i] as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

It's too bad that [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) is down at the moment, it would be easier to show you.

Comment: I have edited the question as this is indeed what im trying to achieve but even using the reference and attempting this, it does not work for me. Any advice?

Comment: What is not working? Is it not outputting the array like you expect?

Comment: its actually not working, as in php page is failing. I am expecting an alert, of which is not occuring due to an error in th php page.

Comment: Let me try something on my local server. In the mean time check your server error logs to see what the failure is, or turn on all error reporting options.

Comment: I have managed to get `print_r($chunked);` returning the whole array now. But, i cannot seem to split the levels with the foreach, as soon as i add the foreach, nothing happens.

Comment: Thats still returning `array` as the value. This is whats confusing me, i tried a foreach within a foreach but to no avail.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51693/discussion-between-stuart-wickenden-and-jay-blanchard)

Comment: ok, have managed to get the values returning with another foreach finally! thankyou so much for your patience.

Comment: You bet! Always happy to help...if I can :)